# How to enable non-interactive authentication when deploying Web project with Azure Webjobs and schedules?

Tags: azure, jenkins, certificate, msdeploy, azure-webjobs

Q: How to enable non-interactive authentication (via management certificates) to multiple subscriptions when deploying Web project with Azure Webjobs and schedules?

Full text:
Some time ago we added an Azure WebJob (scheduled) to our Azure/.NET project. We really liked the simplicity until we tried to deploy it, especially using CI. We use Jenkins for "one click" deployment to production.

However, in order for the WebJobs to get published with the Web project (and especially for the Scheduler to get created), we needed to enable [Non-Interactive Azure Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/), which was an unpleasant surprise that came with WebJobs. But we solved that by adding "webjob.props" file to the Properties of WebJob project that contains Management certificate. Here's the the code:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="AfterSetScheduleProperties" AfterTargets="SetScheduleProperties">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagementCertificate>Here is the cert.</ManagementCertificate>
        <SubscriptionId>Here was our production subscription ID</SubscriptionId>
      </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So now finally the question: we need to support deployment from our CI (Jenkins) to multiple subscriptions. And Non-Interactive Authentication should work for all of them. What would be the easiest way of achieving this? I cannot find a good resource on this topic. I was thinking of somehow making build configuration specific transformations of webjobs.props file. But I would like to avoid this if possible with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

Deploying a scheduled WebJob consists in two distinct parts:

1. Deploying the WebJob files to the Web App
2. Setting up the scheduler

I'm guessing that your issue relates more to #2 than to #1. The good news is that there is an alternate way of scheduling a WebJob using CRON expressions, and this works simply by deploying files to your Web App (so no #2). You can find more details about it [in the documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON).